# Синтаксис cpp (exception ntdll.dll)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, нейронные-сети, float

Давно не писал на плюсах, но синтаксис то уж, вроде, помню. Вылетает эсепшн при попытке выделении памяти (в строке, где создается sum и выделяется под нее память):

```
int Newron::Handle(int inputs[])
{
    float *sum = new float[m];
    //float sum[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        sum[i] = 0;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            sum[i] += w[j][i] * inputs[j];
        }
    }
    int maxIndex = FindMax(sum); // Находим максимально значимый 
    delete[] sum;
    return maxIndex;
}
```

> Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x77DC4BA4 (ntdll.dll) в New_NNKoh.exe:
> 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xBEA1E89B.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем я грешу. Полный код [здесь](https://github.com/HonkyMan/Kohonen-Newron-Network/blob/master/New_NNKoh.cpp)
Второй день борюсь, конкретно таких траблов не нашел на просторах всея сети
Спасибо)

Comment: @SmInc: Не совсем понятно, что за чушь вы написали про ваш "+= на самом деле заменяется на =". Это не так и обнуление тут нужно. Правильный ответ на вопрос: разрушена структура кучи, поэтому выделение памяти падает. Разрушена она записью за пределы массива или еще чем-то в этом роде. Не тем выходом за пределы, который указан в ответе Vladimir (там только чтение), а тем, что указан в ответе AlexGlebe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В SetWeight тоже самое перепутали n с m

```
inline void Newron::SetWeights()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
          w[i][j] = (RAND_MAX * rand()) % 2 / sqrt(m) - 1 / sqrt(m);
```

Имена переменных можно сделать поприкольнее, чтобы было понятно/

Comment: Вот это и есть правильный ответ. В функции `SetWeights` происходит **запись** за пределы выделенной памяти, которая приводит к разрушению целостности кучи, которое в последующем и вызывает падение при попытке выделения памяти.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в `FindMax()` стоит цикл: `for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)`, т.е. до `n`. А Вы скармливаете массив размером `m`. Вот и выходите за диапазон индексов у `sum`.

Comment: Спасибо, и вправду... Уже и такое не замечаю

Comment: @Kamil NHOT: Что за чушь? В вопросе у вас сказано, что падение происходит в строчке `float *sum = new float[m];`. Однако ошибка в `FindMax(sum)` (которая действительно есть) к такому падению привести не может. Может упасть сам `FindMax(sum)`, но не выделение памяти. Выделение памяти падает по другой причине.

Comment: Я просто соглашусь с  AnT ,  тут ошибка есть, но  такая ошибка просто приведет к неправильным результатам.  Это не ответ на вопрос

Comment: @AnT, В общем-то да, в нескольких местах было неправильное обращение к указателю, когда везде поменял, ошибка ушла. Просто этот ответ, так скажем, вдохновил на реальный ответ, спасибо всем